# Java: Would calling clear() on a List free up memory immediatly?

Tags: java, performance

Which would clear up memory quicker:

Given we have a linked list, in this case ArrayList, but feel free to explain this for other lists:

```
ArrayList<String> list = ...10000 elements
```

**Either A)**

```
list.clear();
System.gc();
```

**Or B)**

```
list = null;
System.gc();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it won't free up the memory immediately. You can't do that.

The memory will be freed as soon as the garbage collector runs. But you can't force it running. You can merely suggest to the JVM that the garbage collector should be run, but it is by no means forced to do so.

Comment: More precisely: Normally, the garbage collector runs "when he wants to". `System.gc();` is like saying "Could you please clean up the memory soon?".

Answer (score 2):

Neither one of them are guaranteed to free memory, unless you can prove those are the only references around to the resources you're trying to free.

Either of those should work, with one additional object (the list itself) freed up in the case of B.

Answer (score 1):

if you use the weakhashmap ,the key is in the list ,you will find list.clear is better

Answer (score 0):

There is a general writeup on Java List behavior and list alternatives over [here](http://javafx2.org/2012/09/03/):

While I haven't dug into the source code, it appears to me that the JDK 7 version of array list is based upon resizable arrays rather than linked lists.  When you call clear, the object still retains a portion of its buffer.

If you set the object to null, then the entire list is eligible for collection (assuming that no other object retains a reference to it).